# basic for loop in Hangman Program

Tags: python

Attempting to write some code for a hangman game, I am new to code and Python in general so my code might seem tedious or inefficient. I specifically need help with the last for loop.

```
import random
def_ = []
colours = ["orange", "blue", "yellow", "red", "gray"]

category = input("Please select a category to play from: 1) Colours - 2) Animals - 3) People: ") #lets only do the colours case for now

if category == "1":
  rannum = random.randint(0, len(colours)-1)
  word = colours[rannum]
  i = 0
  print(word)
  for i in range(len(word)):
    def_.append("_")

  wordlist = str.lower(word)
  i = 0
  x = 0

  for i in range(0,8):
    guess = input("Please enter a letter that you think is in the word: ")
    for x in range(0, len(wordlist)):
      if str.lower(guess) == wordlist[x]:
        def_[x] = wordlist[x]
        print("".join(def_))
      else:
        print("".join(def_))
        continue
```

For example, if the colour is `blue` and the user guesses `u`, I want the program to display `__u_`, rather, the program displays:

```
____
____
__u_
__u_
```

I believe the program is looping however long the string is and is looking to see if the character entered matches the character involved in that iteration and each time it is printing the line, rather, I want it to display it only once.

Comment: print outside the loop instead of inside?

Comment: If thats the only code inside of that for loop then the `else/continue` is also not needed

Comment: @arbazhasan did some of the answers help you? or do you still have problems? if one of the answers did answer please mark it as the accepted answer or provide some information of what is still wrong and maybe we can help you to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `print` in the `else` statement and it will work fine (you can also completely remove the `else` statement as it is useless). Also, as [Morten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7884072/morten) pointed out, you should move the `print` out of the `if` statement to avoid multiple print in case you got more than one matching letter.

Edit: a little tip, you do not need to declare and inizialize the variables before using them in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `print` from the `for`-loop and put it after the `for`-loop and see what happens ;)

If you keep it in the `if` statement it will be printed multiple times for words that contain multiple instances of a letter. eg when yellow is the word then you get the printout for "__l___" and "__ll__" if you keep it in the `if`-statement and remove it from the `else`-statement.